How to secure API consuming project using context?
I have a C# .net MVC project in which I am consuming API's from a different project. At first login API is called and if the result is success then, I have phone otp verification, if verification has succeeded then session is created. I was told to implement a context for each request after login, so that the application is more secured.
Can anyone help me in what I need to do as I am new in this?
HttpContext.Session.SetString("email", authResponse.result.email);
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("UserId", authResponse.result.id);

